# Amazon MWS Feed API Issue in updating Order status

Tags: amazon-mws

I am working on amazon mws feed api to update the order status from my site.
when i call to **SubmitFeed** Api, it is submitted successfully.
But, when i call to **GetFeedSubmissionResult**, its returns me an error stating  :

```
        <Result>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.</ResultDescription>
        </Result>
```

Here is the my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>Maxvite Store</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>123-5454545-5454545</AmazonOrderID>
            <MerchantOrderID>123456</MerchantOrderID>
            <MerchantFulfillmentID>123456</MerchantFulfillmentID>
            <FulfillmentDate>12-02-2013T04:23:00Z</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
                <ShippingMethod>UPS Ground</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>123456</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
         </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your feed does not validate against the XSD schema. You cannot specify both AmazonOrderID and MerchantOrderID in the same feed (it is specified as *choice* in the [OrderFulfillment.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/OrderFulfillment.xsd))

Also, your FulfillmentDate should read `2013-02-12T04:23:00+00:00`.

The following feed is changed accordingly and does validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>Maxvite Store</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>123-5454545-5454545</AmazonOrderID>
            <MerchantFulfillmentID>123456</MerchantFulfillmentID>
            <FulfillmentDate>2013-02-12T04:23:00+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
                <ShippingMethod>UPS Ground</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>123456</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
         </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Hazzit-- thanks, you are great,,, it worked,,, actually, i was looking at an example from amazon documentation, and the fullfilment date format there was 2013-02-03T03:03:00 -- thats why i was using that wrong format and was getting error -- now the problem is solved,,,  
Thanks agains :)

Comment: whether feed should be acknowledged before updating shipping?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `<item>` section:

```
<Item>
     <MerchantOrderItemID>1234567</MerchantOrderItemID>
     <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>1234567</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
     <Quantity>2</Quantity>
</Item>
```

Although the XSD shows `minOccurs="0"`, it *may* required in some circumstances. (I've found some weird behaviors with some of the feeds)

That being said, the [MWS forum](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2441221&#2441221) is reporting an identical issue affecting multiple people, so it could be a MWS thing...

Comment: I have tried it with <Item> section, but it does not resolve the problem. I have seen the same issue on MWS Forum but it has no solution there,, :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tag:
123456

it should be either "AmazonOrderID" or "MerchantOrderID".

You can leave out the  cantainer.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed "CarrierCode" from 'Fed Ex' to 'FedEx' - Removed the space and it is working fine now.