# "one or more items are invalid" in Amazon MWS XML Feed

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services

This is similar to this question, however the answer does not seem to work in my situation: [Amazon MWS Feed API Issue in updating Order status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859841/amazon-mws-feed-api-issue-in-updating-order-status)

I am submitting the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>1234567</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderFulfillment>
        <AmazonOrderID>000-1111111-2222222</AmazonOrderID>
        <MerchantFullfillmentID>1234567</MerchantFullfillmentID>
        <FulfillmentDate>2016-04-27T16:13:46-05:00</FulfillmentDate>
        <FulfillmentData>
            <CarrierName>UPS</CarrierName>
            <ShippingMethod>UPS Ground</ShippingMethod>
            <ShipperTrackingNumber>1234567</ShipperTrackingNumber>
        </FulfillmentData>
        <Item>
            <MerchantOrderItemID>SKU</MerchantOrderItemID>
            <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>SKU</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Item>
    </OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I am receiving this message when I check the feed status:

```
<Result>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
    <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
    <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.</ResultDescription>
</Result>
```

Are there any clear errors in this document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I notice that is diffrent than my code is I use:

```
<CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
```

instead of your,

```
<CarrierName>UPS</CarrierName>
```

also I dont think it will cause many problems but you can try not submitting item info, I was having problems and stopped sending item info and it works great, just try cutting out:

```
    <Item>
        <MerchantOrderItemID>SKU</MerchantOrderItemID>
        <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>SKU</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Item>
```

Comment: I tried the first option - did not make a difference, but I tried removing the item info, like you suggested, and it works... which means Amazon's system is basically broken at a fundamental level - but I can get by with this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I agree that its weird, I actually forgot about the removal and was reviewing my code and saw that I commented out the item stuff and left a comment saying "I hope this works" and now I remember having similar problems to you. If it worked for you, please mark as complete.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same return."We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed."

But my issue is filled "FEDEX" instead of "FedEx", It seems case sensitive.
After check the document in https://sellercentral.amazon.com/help/hub/reference/G641 and change to "FedEx",the bug got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Item>
    <MerchantOrderItemID>SKU</MerchantOrderItemID>
    <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>SKU</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Item>
```

MerchantFulfillmentItemID is not  filled "sku"

<xsd:element name="MerchantFulfillmentItemID" type="IDNumber"
minOccurs="0"/>

```
<xsd:simpleType name="IDNumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:positiveInteger">
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{1,20}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

=========================

xsd 下载地址.txt
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Inventory.xsd

amzn-base.xsd
amzn-header.xsd `enter code here`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).